# How to 'blow away' a GIT merge and start fresh?

Tags: git

I run into this scenario more often that I'd like to:

- I check out a branch
- edit one file
- go to push
- am told branches have diverged and I need to merge 100 changes

This usually happens when someone pushes an update right before I do.

Now, I know the best solution is that I need to remember to `pull` before pushing. But when I forget, I get stuck with GIT constantly telling me I need to merge everything.

I've tried `git checkout .` to 'clear' it and start over but that doesn't work. I've also tried to force checkout. In either case, it says I still have merges to commit.

Is there a simple way to just take my current state and 'blow it away' so I can re-check out and just re-edit the one file?

Comment: `git reset --hard HEAD^`

Comment: https://xkcd.com/1597/

Comment: @DrEval yep. that could probably be the answer to *all* git questions. :)

Comment: `git checkout <commitId>` to a previous commit id before diverge

Comment: @marcusshep what does that reset it to?

Comment: @KoushikChatterjee how do I know which commitId to use?

Comment: you can see the log, with `git log --oneline` and will get all the commit id with message. also you can do `git log --oneline -5` to see last 5 (or N) commits with message

Comment: @DA.: both `HEAD^` (which means `HEAD^1`) and `HEAD~1` (which means `HEAD` followed by `^` one time, e.g., `HEAD~3` means `HEAD^^^` for instance) are instructions saying "find the first parent of `HEAD`". The number after a `^` selects *which parent;* for a merge, there are at least two, hence `HEAD^1` and `HEAD^2`. When using the `~` notation you are instructing Git to look only at first parents every time. That's sensible since the first parent is usually the interesting one, even for a merge commit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to run `git reset HEAD~1` before you run `git checkout .`. Which will cause your last commit to be "undone" and the changes will be in a "pre-add" stage. Which you then blow away with the checkout.

Alternatively, you can accomplish both of these routines in one command.

```
git reset --hard HEAD^
```

This will result in the last commit being undone and HEAD will be pointed to the previous commit before you made any changes. Which will most likely be the commit your colleague started her work from.

This needs to happen before you pull in your colleagues commit(s).

Comment: ah...nice! and this command actually makes sense (reset!). That did the trick!

Answer (score 2):

If I understand the question, I think what you actually mean is:

- I check out a branch
- *some time passes*...
- edit one file
- *some more time passes*...
- go to push
- am told branches have diverged and I need to merge 100 changes

Happens on active projects all the time. Nothing is wrong with doing a Pull at this point which would automatically do a merge, and after that, provided there were no conflicts, you'll be able to Push (if there were conflicts you'll have to resolve them sooner or later *anyway*).

But some teams don't like how the history looks after that (on an active project this can get out of hand). So another solution is to do a Fetch-and-Rebase. That will find your commits, undo them, fetch the new commits and re-apply your commits on top of that. Then you can Push, and the history will look as one line, at the cost of accuracy (your commits took place at another time in history).

Comment: This is a good answer too. Sounds like I should just let the merges happen. That said, I'm a front end dev and I'm usually only changing one line of CSS or a couple lines of HTML in one file, so I think I just like the idea of treading lightly and just 'resetting things' and putting in that one change. Yes, GIT intimidates me. :)

Comment: Expect the `push` to fail, that's normal, do a `fetch` followed by `rebase` and `push` (though you can skip the initial `push`). Be careful with a hard reset. You can lose your changes (that's the purpose of it).